# How to create an event in c# when the coordinates of 2 picture boxes meet

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I am creating a game in visual studio forms using c#. I would like to create an event where if the coordinates of picture_box_A == coordinates of picture box_b/c/d... an event is raised. Thanks for support.

Comment: Are you trying to use WinForm PictureBoxes for your game sprites? Those are UI controls and are entirely unsuited for interactive games. You should be creating a single Canvas control and doing all your graphics inside that. In fact, WinForms is a poor choice for high-framerate interactive graphics, you will never get good performance from it.

Comment: That depends on how you're moving your picture box. But if you're really trying to make a game out of it, I wouldn't recommend Windows Forms. Getting into XNA or Monogame will be a better choice for your first game, and it will make handles like this easier to make.

Comment: Do actually mean 'when the locations are equal' or maybe 'when the bounding rectangles overlap'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the [Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.move?view=netframework-4.8) event for each of your `PictureBox` controls. The event handler could look something like:

```
private void PictureBoxMoved(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pb1.Location == pb2.Location)  // Replace pb1 and pb2 with actual control names
        MyEvent?.Invoke();  // pass args depending on your event handler delegate
}
```

Comment: I created coordinates by using (location.X + width/2),location.Y + height/2) so yes it was coordinates. Thank you for your help